# Bootstrap Radiobutton JS Not working due stopPropagation();

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Continue from [Event difference bootstrap collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308719/event-difference-bootstrap-collapse)

At moment I've some code like

```
 <p data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#a" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="a">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></p>
 <div id="a" class="collapse">
  <ul class="faulttab nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
   <li role="presentation" class="active">
   <a href="#a-a" aria-controls="a-a" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">a-a</a></li>
   <li role="presentation" class="active">
   <a href="#a-b" aria-controls="a-b" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">a-b</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="a-a">
   <form>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="invchs">Investigation</label>
      <div class="btn-group col-lg-10" data-toggle="buttons">
       <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" value="0" autocomplete="off" checked>Not Needed
       </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
       <input type="radio" name="options" value="1" autocomplete="off">Needed
      </label>
     </div>//col-lg-10
    </div>//formgorup
   </form>
 </div>//a-a
 <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="a-b">
   <form>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="invchs">Investigation</label>
      <div class="btn-group col-lg-10" data-toggle="buttons">
       <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" value="0" autocomplete="off" checked>Not Needed
       </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
       <input type="radio" name="options" value="1" autocomplete="off">Needed
      </label>
     </div>//col-lg-10
    </div>//formgorup
   </form>
 </div>//a-b
</div>//collapse
```

(something like this but not totally 100% a like because it's too huge to post in here)

And my JS code like

```
$('.collapse').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

These is collapse from that when i click something it's when extend out form and to prevent collapse form to being collapse without filling anything (or click somewhere else) so i put `stopPropagation();` that is why

I've also don't know what's wrong but my first guess is `stopPropagation();` make radio button not working properly

**Things Happen is Radio button JS is not working (HTML working fine)**

- *Not working in these case mean When i click another radio button the other one didn't reset back to un-check states but in HTML every thing working fine*

Any way to fixes this ?

As the same ... Change only JS would be great

Thanks

Comment: That is the exact reason why stop propagation is dangerous

Comment: If you can share teh code that deals with the expand/collapse we can have a look at that and redesign it

Comment: @ArunPJohny can `event.preventDefault();` be useful on this or no?is it different from `stopPropagation();`

Comment: lol i'm trying to manual code to call the function i've seen something in [link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript) like `$().button('toggle')` but i've no idea how to use $this :O

Comment: @BrownmanRevival OPS! .... i've change stopPropagation(); to event.preventDefault(); and it's working but i don't know will it cause anything that i design before //still checking

Comment: @TrinPongtaman both those have completely different functions.... so unless we have a look at the code that is dealing with the collapse/expand we won't be able to offer a solution

Comment: i've updated let's see :) at the moment i've figured out to use `preventDefault();` instead `stopPropagation();` but i still want to know any way to fixes the question before